# Exclude tag from style if with tag falls below other tag/class name

Tags: css

I want to only style a tag if it does not exists under a specific tag.

I want one css selector to be able to handle scenario1 and scenario2 as per the sample below. The selector should colour the tag "bdi" with the text 1300 and 1400 but exclude "bdi" tag with text 1500 because that "bdi" tag is a child of the "del" tag.

I was hoping the [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector could help but I can't seem to get it working.

Thank you

```css
    .price .amount bdi {
        color:red;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    
    <div class="scenario1">
        <p class="price">
            <span class="amount">
                <bdi>1300</bdi>
            </span>
        </p>    
    </div>    

    <div class="scenario2">
        <p class="price">
            <del>
                <span class="amount">
                    <bdi>1500</bdi>
                </span>
            </del>
            <ins>
                <span class="amount">
                    <bdi>1400</bdi>
                </span>
            </ins>
        </p>    
    </div>    


<div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```css
.price > .amount > bdi,
.price > ins > .amount > bdi {
        color:red;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    
    <div class="scenario1">
        <p class="price">
            <span class="amount">
                <bdi>1300</bdi>
            </span>
        </p>    
    </div>    

    <div class="scenario2">
        <p class="price">
            <del>
                <span class="amount">
                    <bdi>1500</bdi>
                </span>
            </del>
            <ins>
                <span class="amount">
                    <bdi>1400</bdi>
                </span>
            </ins>
        </p>    
    </div>    


<div>
```

By specifying that `.amount` must be the direct descendant of `.price`, you rule out the possibility of there being a `del` element 'between' the two. Similarly, you can specify an `ins` element between them in a selector.

Comment: Thank you, that covers scenario1 but it fails on scenario2.

Comment: As asked in my question. 

I want one css selector to be able to handle scenario1 and scenario2 as per the sample below. The selector should colour the tag "bdi" with the text 1300 and 1400 but exclude "bdi" tag with text 1500 because that "bdi" tag is a child of the "del" tag.

Comment: scenario1 does not have a INS or DEL tag and scenario2 has a INS and DEL tag, in scenario2 I want the BDI tag in the INS to be styled with the red text but not the BDI tag under the DEL tag should not be styled.

Comment: I've updated this answer to also style where there is an `ins` tag.